# How to reselect items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

This is google translator

1. Keep the selected item value
2. Reselect the already selected item
3. How can I bring back the same item again?

I try `Selecteditem = null`

But another pane use to selecteditem value.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BizPlaceItems}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBizPlaceItem}" 
/>
```

**C#**

```
public ViewClassName SelectedBizPlaceItem
{
     get => GetPropertyValue<ViewClassName>();
     set
     {
         SetPropertyValue(value);
         if (value == null)
            AppResolver.Info.SelectedBizPlace = null;
         else
            AppResolver.Commands.SelectedBizPlaceCommand.Execute(value);
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to store the `SelectedBizPlaceItem` value to a private property e.g., `OldSelectedItem` before you set the new value. Then restore the previous value by assigning the`OldSelectedItem` to the`SelectedBizPlaceItem` property.

Comment: solved the problem thx!!